# HTTP self-hosting and unit tests

Tags: nunit, dotnet-httpclient, self-hosting

I am working on a set of unit tests, which include testing of HTTP client/server functionality, with a self hosted server. But I can't get even the simplest test to work. HEre is my code

UnitTest1.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using SomeWebService;

    namespace UnitTestProject1
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [Test]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9876");
                var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
                new Bootstrap().Configure(config);
                var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
                using (var client = new HttpClient(server))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
                    var response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
                    Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "Actual status code: " + response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Bootstrap.cs

```
    using System.Web.Http;

    namespace SomeWebService
    {
        public class Bootstrap
        {
            public void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "API Default", routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}", defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

and the HomeController.cs

```
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;

    namespace SomeWebService
    {
        class HomeController:ApiController
        {
            public HttpResponseMessage Get()
            {
                return this.Request.CreateResponse();
            }
        }
    }
```

The test results in:

```
      Actual status code: NotFound
      Expected: True
      But was:  False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Packages installed

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http -version 2.0.20710
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost -version 4.0.20918
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 4.0.20710
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HomeController` is private, because you haven't explicitly declared it public. Try making it public:

```
public class HomeController:ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return this.Request.CreateResponse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your tests to run even faster, you can avoid the whole TCP/IP stack by using a purely in-memory host,

```
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            new Bootstrap().Configure(config);
            var server = new HttpServer(config);
            using (var client = new HttpClient(server))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
                var response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
                Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "Actual status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
```